# Why is empty dict returning when posting form data from react to flask?

Tags: python, reactjs, json, flask, post

This is my react.js code. I am using fetch() to send a POST request (days) to my flask backend server. Days is the input of a form.
here is the on submit function:

```
const submitHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  const postData = {days}
  console.log(postData)
  const response = fetch("/days", {
    method:"POST",
    cache: "no-cache",
    mode: 'no-cors',
    headers:{
        "Content_Type":"application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(postData)
  })
}
```

here is the form:

```
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}> 
          <input type="text" className="form-control" name="days" value={days} onChange={(e)=>{setDays(e.target.value)}}/> 
          <button type="submit">
          Submit
          </button>

      </form>
```

This is the flask:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin
import requests
import json
from web3 import Web3

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)


@app.route('/days', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
  def days():
  return request.form
```

This ends up returning an empty dict like this whenn I run localhost flask server

```
{}
```

I have tried many different versions of request including request.form, request.json, request.get_json, request.args, and more. request.form returns the empty dict and all the other ones return errors.

I am a complete beginner and just simply want this form data on the backend but have no idea where to go from here as it feels like I have tried everything.
Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Could you please let us know if you are getting any errors in the Chrome developer console? :-)

Have you tried adding "OPTIONS" to the list of methods? You may be facing a CORS error for the OPTIONS request.

Comment: There are no errors on any chrome console neither on the client or server side. And I do not believe I ama facing a CORS error as there are not any errors. For some reason flask cannot interpret the post.